# R - POST json with httr

Tags: r, json, httr

I am experiencing some trouble using `POST()`.

I am unsure how to specify the `body()` when the json is a bit more complicated.

A simple example like this works fine:

```
POST(url = url,
     add_headers(Key = "authorization", 
          Authorization = paste("Bearer", accessToken, sep = " ")),
     body = list(Name = "Test"), encode = "json")
```

But when the json is more complex, for example:

```
{
     "Supplier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
     "PurchaseOrderLines": [
     {
          "Item" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "PurchaseOrderID" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "QuantityInPurchaseUnits" : 5.0
     }
     ]
}
```

How do I create a body for this json code? My guess was the following:

```
POST(url = url,
     add_headers(Key = "authorization", 
          Authorization = paste("Bearer", accessToken, sep = " ")),
     body = list(Supplier = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
                 PurchaseOrderLines = list(
                          Item = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
                          PurchaseOrderID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                          QuantityInPurchaseUnits = "5.0")) 
     encode = "json")
```

This returns HTML status 400 so apparently something is wrong with the call. Is my `body()` correct or am I missing something?

EDIT: you can find the API docs over [here](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=PurchaseOrderPurchaseOrders).

Comment: If the endpoint wants a number for `QuantityInPurchaseUnits` why are you giving it a string? Seems like this is just a "typo" error on your part. `POST` with `encode="json"` unboxes the really-no-so-complex list structure exactly as the API expects (well, as you claim it does, since we have no link to said API docs). You also left an errant `,` in your `POST` example.

Comment: @hrbrmstr sorry about the extra `,`. I obviously do no have that in my original code. Also, I tried `QuantityInPurchaseUnits = 5.0` but ended up with the same outcome. Besides that, I am correct to use `list()` for the `PurchaseOrderLines`?

Comment: Edited my question to include a link to the API docs.